# How to Dump a .NET Core Application on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, dump

I have a .NET application that I have ported to .NET Core. I am testing it on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am trying to figure out how to get a .dmp file or the Linux equivalent when the program crashes. I call `Environment.FailFast` but as far as I can tell this doesn't generate a .dmp file like it does on Windows. Acording to [this case](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1321) `Environment.FailFast` should be creating a dump but if it is I can't find it.

In addition I have tried manually creating a dump using `gcore`. This works however it takes a long time to generate the dump (my application isn't that big) and I am unable to get the correct callstacks in gdb after the fact as when I point gdb to my application dll it doesn't recognize it.

What it he best way to get a dump of a .NET Core application on Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an entry in `/var/crash`? It should create an entry there when  an application crashes.

Comment: @MihailStancescu nope, `/var/crash` is empty.

Comment: @MihailStancescu I didn't see any link to say that folder `/var/crash` will be the place for dump, could you clarify?

Answer (score 7):

The generation of linux coredumps is defined by what's in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. If certain signals (e.g. `SIGSEGV` or `SIGQUIT`) cause a process to terminate, an image of the process's memory is basically written into that file. If it starts with a pipe-symbol `|`, it can be streamed into an application which does dump analysis. It's documented here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html

If you configure it like that:

```
   echo coredump > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

it will write a file named `coredump` into the current directory.

If you configure it like that:

```
   echo "/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

It will create a file like `/tmp/cores/core.bash.8539.drehbahn-mbp.1236975953` (see https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/)

As others suggested, also set `ulimit -S -c unlimited` to allow coredumps of any size.

Here is a blog-post which shows how to create and analyze .NET Core coredumps under linux: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2017/02/26/analyzing-a-net-core-core-dump-on-linux/

Comment: I've tried the `echo core > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`, and added my .NET CORE 2.1 console app to `Daemon` mode by writing the file under `/etc/systemd/system`, I killed the process but could not find the dump file, any suggestion?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Good news!: Now you can install a tool to get the dump automatically.

First you run `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-dump` then you can `dotnet-dump [-h|--help] [--version] <command>`

For more info and examples see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump

Answer (score 2):

you want a core dump, this is built into the OS.

first `ulimit -Sc unlimited` as the user you want to run the process as so allow creating a core file of any size.
Then `kill -4 <pid>`

This should generate the core dump.
It should probably be in the directory where the process was run from.

If you can't login as the user the application runs as, you will need to put this into limits.conf.

Comment: I ran `ulimit -Sc unlimited` and then started a dotnet process. After running  `kill -4 <dotnet_pid>` I couldn't find any core dump file in the dll location or `var/crash`

Comment: Is `/var/crash` writable by the user? (It should've sticky bit set but some distributions disable it.)

Comment: @dond yes the user can write to `/var/crash`

Answer (score -2):

I can get core dump by Using `Environment.FailFast("core dump")` in my C# code. Maybe you need to set core dump size and location with `ulimit -c unlimited` and `echo coredump > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` first.

> [xxx/tmp]$ ls core*
>
> core.dotnet.10470