# .Net Core DebugDiag Equivalent

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, debugdiag

For .Net 4.6.x, I have heavily relied upon [DebugDiag 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugdiag/)

Anytime Production applications had high CPU issues, deadlocks, etc, I would use that tool to capture dumps of w3svc and it prints out a nice report of what all the threads were doing.  They may be waiting on 3rd party APIs, databases, etc.

I want to move to asp.net core, but if I had a production server w/ 100% CPU or issues like mentioned above, I can't find any way you can dump all the threads in a process and see their stack trace.

How are people getting around not having this visibility available to them? Am I missing something? I'm looking for a solution that works in Linux as well.

Comment: what about ProcDump? it can dump the .net core app create full memory dump

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I don't think that runs on linux

Comment: no, it does not. But where in your question it says anything about linux?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Good point.  I'll make an edit.  When I think of .net core production, I think of linux for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Dump a .NET Core Application on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070270/how-to-dump-a-net-core-application-on-linux)

Comment: @LexLi it's not.  Getting a dump is step 1, my questions is also about analyzing the stack trace of all the threads.

Comment: The analysis provided by DebugDiag can be carried manually. So before Microsoft creates something for you, you can always help yourself. Personally I don't think DebugDiag analyzes the dumps in the most meaningful way (well all automation tools have such limitations).

Comment: @LexLi Disagree. It's invaluable.  Ho would I "carry it manually"

Comment: DebugDiag2 runs on Linux?

Comment: @LexLi I think that dump on demand and auto-analyze were the less interesting features. I would say that the most interesting one was dump on (specific) first chance exception, and I don't know of a .NET core/5 equivalent of that unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend IDA which is a debugger and disassembler.  It runs on Linux and can be used to dump all the threads and perform stack trace.  [Here is a link to it.](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) Or Microsoft now allows you to debug directly from Visual Code Studio and dump threads onto there.  There are multiple tutorials on that and a quick Google Search can help or viewing the Microsoft help center.  Check that out [here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio)

Comment: This question is asking for the equivalent to DebugDiag ... DebugDiag was able to just point at a dump file and it would generate a report highlighting the issues and it would output a simple list of the threads with stack traces. I tried IDA evaluation edition and this is not equivalent - it seems to be a low level utility like WinDbg, which is not what this question is looking for.